# Make carousel thumbnails responsive in mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, thumbnails

I have this carousel element with 4 associated thumbnails. It looks and works fine in desktop and tablet mode, but when I switch to phone I get this view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFg8y.png

I want the 4 thumbnails to have the same size and to align horizontally. They are not necessarily of the same resolution.

This is the ul containing the thumbnails:

```
<ul class="hide-bullets">

    <li class="col-sm-3 hidden-phone">
       <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/BL-Kokk01.jpg"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-sm-3">
       <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/BL-Kokk02.jpg"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-sm-3">
       <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/BL-Stue01.jpg"></a>
    </li>

    <li class="col-sm-3">
       <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/Blokhus ude.jpg"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've overwritten the bootstrap CSS:

```
.img-responsive, .thumbnail > img, .thumbnail a > img, .carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    /*height: auto;*/
}

.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
}
```

I tried playing around with the width and height properties, but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `col-xs-3` instead of `col-sm-3`

```
<ul class="hide-bullets">
  <li class="col-sm-3 hidden-phone"> 
          <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/BL-Kokk01.jpg"></a> 
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"> 
           <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/BL-Kokk02.jpg"></a> 
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"> 
           <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/BL-Stue01.jpg"></a> 
    </li>
    <li class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3"> 
      <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="images/sommerhuse/blokhus/Blokhus ude.jpg"></a> 
    </li>
</ul>
```